# jQuery find element :contains, then get class

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron, nightmare

I am trying to get the class name of this item but it keeps returning undefined.

```
var className = $(':contains("TRI-PACK PERTEX JACKET HIBISCUS")').attr('class');
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yihqf.png): [Here is the class I want it to return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yihqf.png)

HTML Page: https://shop.palaceskateboards.com/

I want to get the class of name of the product based on keywords later I will use nightmare JS to click that class.

Comment: `attr()` will only read from the first found element when called on a collection, and that's very unlikely to be the `h3` as you expect as it will also hit every parent element. I'd suggest trying `h3:contains(...`. If that doesn't work please add your actual HTML to the question (not just a picture of it) so we can see the exact context of the problem.

Comment: It's ugly, and a pseudoselector **and** an attribute selector (*shudders*), but you could try: `var className = $('[class]:contains("TRI-PACK PERTEX JACKET HIBISCUS")').attr('class');` which would only select the things that contain the text, and also have a class attribute

Comment: @Taplar Returns undefined in console.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Added page so you can look at the HTML.

Comment: I get jQuery is not defined on that page.

Comment: sorry @SPLYSPLY, but just to be sure of what you're asking, by "className" you really mean the css class ? or you're calling "className" to the product keywords and you want to search by them and return their object ?

Answer (score 0):

`:contains` is a too general selector. If it matches, it'll literally select every single element that contains a string - in a chain.

Say you're looking for `:contains('foo')`

```
<body>     <!-- Yep contains "foo" therefore gets selected -->
   <div>   <!-- Yep contains "foo" therefore gets selected -->
      I'm a DIV
      <p>  <!-- Yep contains "foo" therefore gets selected -->
          foobar                   <!-- humm... foobar? :D -->
      </p>
   </div>
</body>
```

by simply doing

```
var $els = $(':contains("foo")')
console.log( $els )
```

you'll see that it's actually an **Array of element*s***. `.attr()` immediately filters the first one. Clearly not the one you tried to find (`body`).

If you know exactly the tag you're trying to query try to be more specific with your selector like `$(".product-info > a > h3:contains('foo')")`.
Otherwise, loop-filter all your elements, make sure that `.text()` returns in it's entirety the desired string.

---

## Search products by name: solution

You already have the `data-alpha="PRODUCT NAME / 1"` - so use it!

```js
var $products = $("[data-alpha]");

$("#search").on("input", function() {
  $products.hide().filter((i, el) => 
    new RegExp(this.value.trim(), 'ig').test(el.getAttribute("data-alpha"))
  ).show();
});

// on scroll don't forget to update $products
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

#product-loop {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
[data-alpha] {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}
[data-alpha]:before{
  content: attr(data-alpha);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search product...">

<div id="product-loop" class="clearfix">
  <div data-alpha="TRI-PACK PERTEX JACKET HIBISCUS" data-price="13800" data-i="1"></div>
  <div data-alpha="ZIP KNIT PEACH / RED" data-price="10800" data-i="12"></div>
  <div data-alpha="S-PLAKET OVERSHIRT RED" data-price="12800" data-i="13"></div>
  <div data-alpha="S-PLAKET OVERSHIRT NAVY" data-price="12800" data-i="14"></div>
  <div data-alpha="DANSE SHIRT BLUE" data-price="11800" data-i="15"></div>
  <div data-alpha="DANSE SHIRT BLACK" data-price="11800" data-i="16"></div>
  <div data-alpha="SERVICE SHORT SLEEVE SHIRT GREEN / WHITE" data-price="9800" data-i="17"></div>
  <div data-alpha="SERVICE SHORT SLEEVE SHIRT BLACK / WHITE" data-price="9800" data-i="18"></div>
  <div data-alpha="PLAIN PANT BLACK" data-price="12800" data-i="19"></div>
  <div data-alpha="PEAKING JEAN MULTI" data-price="15800" data-i="20"></div>
  <div data-alpha="P-CARP PANT BLACK" data-price="12800" data-i="21"></div>
  <div data-alpha="P-CARP PANT NAVY" data-price="12800" data-i="22"></div>
  <div data-alpha="DANSE PLAIN PANT BLACK" data-price="12800" data-i="23"></div>
  <div data-alpha="PALACE JEAN BLACK STONEWASH" data-price="12800" data-i="24"></div>
  <div data-alpha="PALACE JEAN STONEWASH" data-price="12800" data-i="25"></div>
  <div data-alpha="PJS PALACE JEAN WHITE DENIM" data-price="12800" data-i="26"></div>
  <div data-alpha="P-LITE RUN IT JACKET ULTRAMARINE" data-price="14800" data-i="27"></div>
  <div data-alpha="P-LITE RUN IT SHORT ULTRAMARINE" data-price="9800" data-i="28"></div>
  <div data-alpha="P-LITE RUN IT JACKET BLACK" data-price="14800" data-i="29"></div>
  <div data-alpha="P-LITE RUN IT SHORT BLACK" data-price="9800" data-i="30"></div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var className = $('h3').filter(":contains('TRI-PACK PETREX JACKET HIBISCUS')").attr('class');
    console.log(className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-info">
<a href=""><h3 class="title">TRI-PACK PETREX JACKET HIBISCUS</h3></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The whole point is the user enters a keyword and it will find the product so .product-info, etc would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score -1):

use prop function and 'className' attribute of DOM

```
var className = $('h3:contains("TRI-PACK PERTEX JACKET HIBISCUS")').prop('className');
```

your selector selects all parent elements, because all of them 'contains' specified text. limit your selector to get response

```
console.log($(':contains("TRI-PACK PERTEX JACKET HIBISCUS")')[0])
```

to make sure that element is selected correctly. and even you can use :

```
var elm = $(':contains("TRI-PACK PERTEX JACKET HIBISCUS")')[0]; 
if(elm){ 
    console.log(elm.className) 
}
```

oh yes. the selector selects 'html' element. change your selector or the way you select

Comment: Returns undefined.

Comment: Both say undefined.

Comment: the selector selects 'html' element. change your selector or the way you select. I'll post correct response a few minutes later